# Switching language with keyboard shortcut in GNOME is ineffective

Tags: gnome, keyboard, language-support

I have Ubuntu 13.04 32-bit with GNOME 3.8.2, and Unity installed too.

Two languages are selected as input sources - English(US) and Russian.

Keyboard shortcut to change input methods is set.

Indicator in top notification panel works well.

The problem is that changing input method by keybinding does not work properly - it changes only the indicator in the top panel and does not affect typing from keyboard. It doesn't matter which language is selected through keyboard shortcut, typing from keyboard brings symbols only from English input method.

But, if I change language from panel (from EN to RU, by example), everything works okay and I can type Russian symbols. Then I again change language, now by keybind (to EN), it works too, but only once, next usage of keybind does not affect input method, leaving only English input.

In Unity everything works, without any problems.

Comment: Can you go to Settings > Keyboard Layout Settings and post a screenshot here?

Comment: same problem [Keyboard shortcut for input language doesn't work on Gnome shell](//askubuntu.com/q/541956)

Answer (score 0):

One possible cause could be an existing bug in Ubuntu, that's been around for a couple of years already: If you press the keyboard shortcut to change a keyboard layout, it will actually change the layout, but not the indication in the panel. For example, you were using Russian in one window, and are now using English in another window. Then you change focus back to the first window. In that case, the keyboard input will automatically switch back to Russian, but the panel indicator will keep showing EN. Further more, if you use the keyboard shortcut to change the input, it will switch back to English, but the indicator will switch to RU.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the keyboard shortcut not working, but changing the language in the notification panel would not work either.

Going to `Settings` -> `Region & Language` and clicking the `Options` button next to **Input Settings**, I was able to select `Allow different sources for each window` and it fixed my problem.  I could even switch back to `Use the same source for all windows` and it continued to work.

*Edit:* Tested on Ubuntu 18.10 and GNOME 3.30.1